# iOs simulator frame rate drop

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm doing my first steps in spriteKit, i only have two scenes, in the second one i have a method which spawns little pixels (rocks) and they fall down with the physic. The other thing I have is a parallax effect with a image.png which size is 323x90. The image move in the background from left to right and when it disappear in the right it spawns again (i don't destroy the node, only change it's position) in the left and begin again the animation.
When the rocks are falling, the node max count is 20 - 21 but my FPS drop to 20-21. This is beginning to slow down and i don't understand why, i wonder what will happen when my scene grows up. I've tried with iphone 5 simulator and is the same. Does any one know why?

Comment: simulator is very bad for fps measuring, always test on real device. For example, my app (with cocos3d, but that does not matter) on simulator show about 2-3 fps which makes it impossible to test, while on device it has 30 fps

Comment: The actual device is always going to be better and more powerful than the simulator.